# I cannot drag across the reputation graph

Tags: bug, google-chrome, reputation-tab

On my profile's activity page in the reputation tab, there is this smaller *[reputation graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=graph)* below which is written

> select an area by dragging across the lower chart

Using Chrome, this does not work, and never worked (it works in Firefox though). The small graph is just not interactive. This means I cannot zoom to any other region than the one shown below. Are there any browser setting which prevent this from working? I checked it on other SE-sites, with the same result (is it wrong to ask here because it is no Math.SE specific problem?). I have no other problems with the SE-sites.

[image]

---

**Update**

I noticed right now that this works fine on *UserExperience StackExchange*! It still fails on many other sites, e.g. WorldBuilder. What is going on? I thought all sites are functioning more or less the same.

Comment: If this is browser dependent and only causes problem in Chrome, probably ([meta-tag:google-chrome]) might be worth adding. However, for me it works in Chrome (Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows - if it's relevant). So maybe let's wait whether somebody else can confirm. (I have also added a link to your post so that it's easier for others to check - I hope that I have linked to the page you have in mind.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Just to check that it is nothing profile dependent: does the dragging work for you when you try it on my profile?

Comment: Yes, it does. Here is [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amXyA.png) where I tried to select June (on your reputation tab), the upper graph was updated after I selected the part in the timeline at the bottom. (At least from the screenshot you can check whether we are talking about the same thing.)

Comment: I also experience this in opera, every time I try to drag, a gray box appears but it never actually selects the area.